# Is it OK to put a fragment of a quote within a paragraph?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, quotations, paragraphs

For example:
She recommends an au pair, a surprisingly more affordable alternative to a nanny, “to take on the role of caregiver when both parents work outside of the home.”

Or should the sentence be reworded entirely?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Apparently the reference is already in the text as something written by the subject of the sentence.

Comment: I can't see how the original can have contained exactly those words (even with others that are omitted in the quote).